# python regex findall <span>

Tags: python, regex

I wanna find all thing between  `<span class="">`  and `</span>`

```
p = re.compile('<span class=\"\">(.*?)\</span>', re.IGNORECASE)
text = re.findall(p, z)
```

for example in this case `<span class="">foo</span>` expected return foo but it returns any thing !!! 
why my code goes wrong ?

Cheers

Comment: [Use an XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/647772)

Comment: don't use regex to parse HTML, use an XML/HTML parser instead

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns anything"?  Provide a runnable example with traceback.  As it is your code should work as my answer shows.

Comment: Tried Your regex and it works just well ...

Comment: I think for this simple scenario, you might get away with a simple regex. As Mark shows, your regex should work. It would fail, however, if there were any newlines inside the `<span>` tag. You'd need to compile the regex using `re.I|re.S`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [HTML is not a regular language, you really should use an XML parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

Comment: "Regular languages" have nothing to do with "regular expressions" (in the CS sense). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11306641/989121

Comment: @thg435: I was more quoting the linked answer than putting much thought into the CS sense of the sentence. Interesting answer, but I find that using a dedicated HTML parser is often the more readable and more maintainable tool for problems like the OPs. :-)

Comment: of course he should use a parser. I just wanted to point out that the term "regular language" is not relevant here. The prominent Funny Post is painfully wrong in this regard.

Comment: @thg435: Noted, I'll avoid the term in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code works as is.  You should use an HTML parser though.

```
import re
p = re.compile('<span class=\"\">(.*?)\</span>', re.IGNORECASE)
z = '<span class="">foo</span>'
text = re.findall(p, z)
print text
```

Output:

```
['foo']
```

**Edit**

As Tim points out, `re.DOTALL` should be used or the below would fail:

```
import re
p = re.compile('<span class="">(.*?)\</span>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
z = '''<span class=""> a more
complicated foo</span>'''
text = re.findall(p, z)
print text
```

Even then it would fail for nested spans:

```
import re
p = re.compile('<span class="">(.*?)\</span>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
z = '''<span class=""> a more
complicated<span class="other">other</span>foo</span>'''
text = re.findall(p, z)
print text
```

Output (failing):

```
[' a more\ncomplicated<span class="other">other']
```

So use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = bs(z)
p = re.compile('<span class="">(.*?)\</span>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
z = '''<span class=""> a more
complicated<span class="other">other</span>foo</span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(z)
print soup.findAll('span',{'class':''})
print
print soup.findAll('span',{'class':'other'})
```

Output:

```
[<span class=""> a more
complicated<span class="other">other</span>foo</span>]

[<span class="other">other</span>]
```

Comment: It would be safer to also specify `re.DOTALL`. Also, all those ugly backslashes can be dropped.

Comment: Sure, and I upvoted your answer for that. But I suspect that the real text contains more than just `foo`, and that that is the actual problem...

Comment: Then the OP should have asked a better question :^)

Comment: Yeah, well I'm feeling generous today, and my crystal ball has just returned from the cleaner's.