# How to find a span containing a particular word

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a webpage. Now I would like to read the Index value `31811.75` from the span:

```
<span>Underlying Index: <b style="font-size:1.2em;">BANKNIFTY 31811.75</b> </span>
```

Unfortunately the span lacks any other identifies such as `class`. I followed the solutions mentioned [on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248723/how-to-find-spans-with-a-specific-class-containing-specific-text-using-beautiful), but I don't seem to get the whole text:

```
>>> print(soup.body(text=re.compile('Underlying')))
['Underlying Index: ']
```

I would like the used the keyword `Underlying` to extract the text present in the span. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a synthetic HTML document that has a **span** that we don't want to find.  Extract decimal from found text using `re.findall()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """
<html><body>
<span>unwanted</span>
<span>Underlying Index: <b style="font-size:1.2em;">BANKNIFTY 31811.75</b> </span>
</html></body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
index = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", soup.find(lambda tag:tag.name=="span" and "Underlying" in tag.text).text )
index[0] if len(index)==1 else None # re.findall() returns a list,  take first located decimal.  Could default to 0.0 instead of None
```

### output

```
'31811.75'
```