# Regular expression to catch as many Javascript redirections as possible

Tags: javascript, python, regex, redirect

I'm trying to catch as many Javascript redirects as possible from many HTML pages. My regular expression is:

```
((location.href)|(window.location)|(location.replace)|(location.assign))(( ?= ?)|( ?\( ?))("|')([^'"]*)("|')( ?\) ?)?;
```

I use Python but the question is general:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""((location.href)|(window.location)|(location.replace)|(location.assign))(( ?= ?)|( ?\( ?))("|')([^'"]*)("|')( ?\) ?)?;""", re.I)
# ... some control here ...
print re.search(regex, html).group(10)  # 10 is the pure url
```

I did some tests and I was able to catch all these cases.

```
location.href = "http://www.foo.com";
location.href="http://www.foo.com";
window.location = "http://www.foo.com";
window.location.href = "http://www.foo.com";
location.replace ("http://www.foo.com");
location.replace( "http://www.foo.com" ) ;
location.assign ("http://www.foo.com");
```

And skip where I can't resolve an URL because the code contains a variable:

```
location.href = "http://www.foo.com" + var + "something else";
```

The questions are:

1. Are there other ways to redirect using Javascript? Other `location.somethingelse` that I am missing?
2. Is the way I catch these 4 cases correct? Is it allowed to have something like `location.href = http://www.foo.com;` or `location.replace (http://www.foo.com);` that I'll miss because of the (double) quotes? Am I too strict or too lax?
3. Is my regex well written? Or can I improve it in some way?

Comment: There's also `document.location`

Comment: The URL should be between double quotes OR single quotes. You'll need to check for both since they are both valid ways to enclose a string in JavaScript.

Comment: @MattBurland, yes, I think I check that with the `("|')` part before and after the url. Am I doing this wrongly?

Comment: @Luca: No, your are correct. I missed the `("|')` part in you regex.

Comment: I had just started the task trying to write regex to do this for my script. Looked everywhere but found your post. Thank you for saving my time, I'll let you know if I think of anything else.

Comment: I did notice that one thing you do not handle are meta http-requiv refreshes. I understand its an old post just wanted to make a mention of it!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot parse programming languages with regexes (well, theoretically [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11382641/989121), but it's extremely unpractical). This is especially true for javascript because of its highly dynamic nature. For example,

```
 window['loc' + 'a' + 'tion'][['h','r','e','f'].join('')] = 'something'.replace(/s/, etc...)
```

That said, here's an expression that at least passes your tests (broken down for clarity):

```py
# quoted string
str = r"""
    ' (?:\\.|[^'])* '
    |
    " (?:\\.|[^"])* "
"""
# dotted reference to "location"
loc = r"""
    (?: \w+\.)*
    \b location \b
    (?: \.\w+)*
"""

# ref=string or ref(string)
expr = r"""
    ({0})
    \s*
    (?:
        = \s* ({1})
        |
        \( \s* ({1}) \s* \)
    )
    \s*
    ;
""".format(loc, str)
```

Compile this in extended mode, e.g.

```
expr = re.compile(expr, re.X)
```

Comment: I'm not interested in this type of expedient, but thank you. I'm doing an extra check, if a webmaster do this in its pages, he deserve to be excluded from my list :)